# pip is not fully installing packages from requirements.txt

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to install python dependencies from a requirements.txt file on my raspberry pi.  This worked fine on an ubuntu VM image I initially tested it on, so I'm a little confused.

When I run `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

```
Collecting coverage
  Downloading https://www.piwheels.org/simple/coverage/coverage-4.5.1-cp35-cp35m-linux_armv6l.whl (208kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 215kB 131kB/s 
Collecting Django
  Downloading Django-2.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (7.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 7.1MB 8.9kB/s 
....
```

There are no errors in the output, so I added the `-v` flag and ran again:

`pip3 install -v -r requirements.txt`

Pretty much the same output, with all the stuff you would expect about finding the right package, connecting to sources, etc.

To confirm any of the packages aren't installed:

`pip3 show <pick a package from my requirements.txt file>`

Which just returns a prompt with no output.

So, I'm just downloading packages and not installing them?  What's up with that?

Here is my requirements file:

```
certifi==2017.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
coverage==4.4.2
Django==2.0.1
gitdb2==2.0.3
GitPython==2.1.9
gunicorn==19.7.1
idna==2.6
netifaces==0.10.6
nose==1.3.7
psycopg2==2.7.3.2
python-nmap==0.6.1
pytz==2017.3
requests==2.18.4
simplejson==3.13.2
smmap2==2.0.3
urllib3==1.22
xml2json==0.1
```

However, if I attempt to install the packages one-by-one it works fine:

```
> pip install certifi
Collecting certifi
  Downloading certifi-2018.1.18-py2.py3-none-any.whl (151kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 153kB 187kB/s 
Installing collected packages: certifi
Successfully installed certifi-2018.1.18
```

So, I don't think it's a dependency issue.

Here is the full output, mind you, I've already tried running this once and the packages were downloaded, and I ran `pip install certifi` & `pip install chardet` manually to show the command works when only attempting to install one package at a time:

```
root@omniscanner:~# pip3 install -r /opt/omnicron-scanner/requirements.txt 
Collecting certifi==2017.11.5 (from -r /opt/omnicron-scanner/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached certifi-2017.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: chardet==3.0.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from -r /opt/omnicron-scanner/requirements.txt (line 2))
Collecting coverage==4.4.2 (from -r /opt/omnicron-scanner/requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/coverage/coverage-4.4.2-cp35-cp35m-linux_armv6l.whl
Collecting Django==2.0.1 (from -r /opt/omnicron-scanner/requirements.txt (line 4))
  Using cached Django-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting gitdb2==2.0.3 (from -r /opt/omnicron-scanner/requirements.txt (line 5))
  Using cached gitdb2-2.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting GitPython==2.1.9 (from -r /opt/omnicron-scanner/requirements.txt (line 6))
  Using cached GitPython-2.1.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting gunicorn==19.7.1 (from -r /opt/omnicron-scanner/requirements.txt (line 7))
  Using cached gunicorn-19.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna==2.6 (from -r /opt/omnicron-scanner/requirements.txt (line 8))
  Using cached idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting netifaces==0.10.6 (from -r /opt/omnicron-scanner/requirements.txt (line 9))
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.6-cp35-cp35m-linux_armv6l.whl
Collecting nose==1.3.7 (from -r /opt/omnicron-scanner/requirements.txt (line 10))
  Using cached nose-1.3.7-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting psycopg2==2.7.3.2 (from -r /opt/omnicron-scanner/requirements.txt (line 11))
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/psycopg2/psycopg2-2.7.3.2-cp35-cp35m-linux_armv6l.whl
Collecting python-nmap==0.6.1 (from -r /opt/omnicron-scanner/requirements.txt (line 12))
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/python-nmap/python_nmap-0.6.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz==2017.3 (from -r /opt/omnicron-scanner/requirements.txt (line 13))
  Using cached pytz-2017.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests==2.18.4 (from -r /opt/omnicron-scanner/requirements.txt (line 14))
  Using cached requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting simplejson==3.13.2 (from -r /opt/omnicron-scanner/requirements.txt (line 15))
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/simplejson/simplejson-3.13.2-cp35-cp35m-linux_armv6l.whl
Collecting smmap2==2.0.3 (from -r /opt/omnicron-scanner/requirements.txt (line 16))
  Using cached smmap2-2.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3==1.22 (from -r /opt/omnicron-scanner/requirements.txt (line 17))
  Using cached urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting xml2json==0.1 (from -r /opt/omnicron-scanner/requirements.txt (line 18))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xml2json==0.1 (from -r /opt/omnicron-scanner/requirements.txt (line 18)) (from versions: 1.1)
No matching distribution found for xml2json==0.1 (from -r /opt/omnicron-scanner/requirements.txt (line 18))
```

Comment: In Raspbian Wheezy, the command for managing Python 3 packages was `pip-3.2`, not `pip3`. Is that a possible error? Also when you type `pip3 freeze` the packages still don't show up?

Comment: I installed Jessie-Lite, so had to install quite a bit by hand.  In this case: `apt-get install python3 python3-pip`.  If I run `pip3 freeze`, it does list packages, but only the standard ones, none of which are part of my `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: Unless you only get this error when running pip from bash, this is purely a Python issue; no need for a bash tag.

Comment: Interesting, I would agree with @CharlesDuffy and say that this is a python issue since it is not able to execute the -r command correctly. From the looks of it, all it does is download the packages for you where you have to manually install them. It seems like a pip issue since it is a problem in particular to how it installs packages. Full functionality has not been correctly implemented on the raspberry pi environment it seems.

Comment: Could you post full output of `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`?

Comment: @Sraw posted the output

Comment: At the end of your posted output, you can see an error `No matching distribution found for xml2json==0.1 (from -r /opt/omnicron-scanner/requirements.txt (line 18))`. You see? That is why nothing is installed.

Comment: I noticed that too.  However, I can install it by hand with no issues.  So, why would it fail through `-r`, but work manually?

Comment: How do you manually install it? By `pip3 install xml2json`? That is not the same brother. In `requirements.txt`, the version is specified. I believe if you try to manuall execute `pip3 install xml2json==0.1`, you will fail. That means you need to update your `reqirements.txt`.

Comment: @Sraw yup, you're right.  I ended up changing the `==` to `>=` in `requirements.txt` and ran again... all worked!

Comment: A better choice, you can first manually install `xml2json`, and see what version is installed. Then change `==0.1` to that version. This will be more stable than using `>=`.